# Specifice order to tables in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I just created a temporary table as:

```
create temporary table userAndProductSales as 
select p.p_name, u.u_name, u.s_price, u.quantity 
from product p 
join userAndStates u 
on p.s_id = u.s_id
```

Now I want to select some columns with a particular order. For example, I want the select to give me an output of:

```
u_name1 p_name1
u_name1 p_name2
u_name1 p_name3
u_name1 p_name4
...

u_name2 p_name1
u_name2 p_name2
u_name2 p_name3
....
```

and so on and so forth. How do I get this ouput? I've tried something on the lines of:

```
select (select u_name from userandproductsales order by u_name), p_name from userandproductsales
```

but I'm getting an error

UPDATE: Figured out that the table I'm joining isn't giving me the correct data I want. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: When getting an error, you should always include it. Also, it is usually good form to add what version of PostgreSQL you are using.

Comment: Also, why are you creating a temp table? Why not just `order by` from your query?

Comment: "order by" isn't giving me the correct output that I want. I'm making a web application so I'm using temp tables for speed reasons

Comment: This is a bad idea. What happens when another session adds a new product? Your "temp" table is out of date.  Don't try to be smarter than PostgreSQL. Unless you have *a lot* of load on the database (and I'm mean 1000s of transactions per second) then just let Postgresql worry about the caching strategy for you.

Comment: This web application is quite simple and I know for sure theres no way another session will add in new products. I also have to access this same table in the same session so using temp tables will help me in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use [ORDER BY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-order.html)    :

```
SELECT * from userandstatesales 
order by u_name , p_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is close but I'm getting an output of

Comment: u_name1 p_name1, u_name1 p_name 2, ..... u_name2 p_name6, u_name2 p_name 7 and so on. I need the p_name to be consistent with u_name just like I pointed out in my question.

Comment: Ok, you should give a data sample storend on your tables.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is a reason for creating a temporary table (like needing to access it later in the same session), you should avoid the expense and simply do a `order by` from your select. For example:

```
select p.p_name, u.u_name, u.s_price, u.quantity 
from product p 
join userAndStates u 
on p.s_id = u.s_id
order by u.u_name, p.p_name;
```

Comment: I am actually accessing the table in the same session so I do need a temporary table. The order by isn't giving me the output I want. It orders the u_name correctly but it's not ordering p_name like I want it to

Comment: @deryl I would probably be helpful to the community in answering your question if you will provide the DDL statements for the two tables and the inserts to populate them.  Then provide the desired out put to your query.